# 0x80072F76 - 0X20017 error when starting Windows 10 Media Creation Tool

Tags: windows-10

I get an error when opening Windows 10 Media Creation Tool: 0x80072F76 - 0X20017.

The tool has just been downloaded from Microsoft's official website and I am trying to run it from a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft phone support and it is a network error (an error code that appears when Terms and Conditions cannot be displayed for user to read and accept them).

Proposed solutions by Microsoft agent:

1. Copy installer to Desktop.
2. Run in Windows 8 compatibility mode.
3. Run in Windows 7 compatibility mode.
4. Restart and run in Windows 8 compatibility mode.
5. Finally, what worked for me: **setup network adapter's IPv4 configuration to use DNS server 9.9.9.9**.

It is a problem betweeen Microsoft and some ISPs (mainly in Spain), they and working on it but can be bypassed using DNS server 9.9.9.9.

Other solutions I could rean on the Internet (deactivating antivirus, setting default web browser to Microsoft Edge...) didn't work.

Comment: Does changing DNS work?

Comment: @Biswa It worked for me. Seems to be a communication problem between ISP and Microsoft's servers, and using 9.9.9.9 (which, by the way, is an IBM DNS server) you make sure you are connected to a network which is currently working. As said by Microsoft's technician, they are working on a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the US in California, my service provider is AT&T and if I use their DNS 68.94.156.1 and 68.84.157.1 I get the same error when the tool tries to get EULA disclaimer. By changing the DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 the problem goes away. Apparently the AT&T DNS does not know the MS server needed for this step.